# How to get value from map on another page in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, hashmap

So I have a listview with which I used Future to fetch data and it displays fine. Now am trying to parse the value on the clicked item from the listview page to another page that will show details of the item click. Please how do I achieve this?

The Future

```
List dealData = List();
  Future<String> _fetchComment() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
      debugPrint("emirate state");
    });
    try {
      debugPrint("emirate try");

      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        print('connected');
        debugPrint("emirate connect");

        String url;

        debugPrint("my select:$_mySelection");

        if (_mySelection == null && _myFeatureSelection == null) {
          url = "my rest api";
          
        } else if (_myFeatureSelection != null) {
          url =
              "my rest api";
          _mySelection = null;
        } else if (_mySelection != null && _myFeatureSelection == null) {
          url = "my rest api";

        }

        print("our url:$url");

        var res = await http
            .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
        var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

        debugPrint("emirate url:$url");

        setState(() {
          dealData = resBody;
          isLoading = false;
        });

        print(resBody);
        debugPrint("emirate:$resBody");

        return "Sucess";
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load profile');
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
      setState(() => isLoading = false);

      Navigator.popUntil(
          context, (_) => !Navigator.canPop(context));


      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => NoInternet()));


    }
  }
```

My listview and onclick

```
dealData
         .map(
   
           (position) => FutureBuilder<String>(
               future: getDistance(
                   position["lat"],
                   position["lng"])
                   .then((value) =>
                   value.toString()),

       builder: (context, snapshot) {


         double myrate = double.parse(
             position["ratings"] ==
                 null
                 ? "0"
                 : position["ratings"]);

         return Container(
             child:Card(child:
             GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {

                   print(position); // position printed here

                   Navigator.push(
                       context,
                       MaterialPageRoute(
                           builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Maps(position)));


                 },
     ).toList(),
```

My Map Class

```
class mapsFinal extends StatefulWidget {
 final int position;

 const mapsFinal(this.position);

 @override
 _MapsState createState() => _MapsState ();
}

class _MapsState extends State<mapsFinal> {
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text("title" + widget.position.toString());
 }
}
```

Please I need a second page that will display the item I clicked on here.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? I see a lot of code about receiving data, but very little on your actual problem. You seem to have code that does what you want, what is the problem with it?

Comment: My code runs fine, am just looking for how to receive "position" on "Maps" page.

Comment: You do already, don't you? Isn't that what `Maps(position)` does?

Comment: Yes, I pushed it with Navigator.push(
                       context,
                       MaterialPageRoute(
                           builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Maps(position)));

already but I don't know how to receive the value in another page "Maps"

Comment: What do you mean "receive"? Does your code compile? Then you received it. Does it not? Then maybe post your Maps class.

Comment: I just add my Maps class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example of passing a value to a widget called "Maps":

```
// BOILERPLATE CODE TO MAKE THE EXAMPLE RUN

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Maps("THE VALUE"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// THIS IS THE CLASS YOU NEED TO LOOK AT:

class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  final String position;
  
  const Maps(this.position);

  @override
  _MapsState createState() => _MapsState ();
}

class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("You passed: " + widget.position);
  }
}
```

Comment: E/flutter (30864): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Comment: Given that my code does not have that error, you will need to post your code, otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: I just update my code with Maps class that is not opening

Comment: So... your poistion is what type? Because if it's not a String, you have to change the data type in the Maps class... I cannot magically know that, you have to adapt the answers you get.

Comment: The issue here is on click on the listview it doesn't go to the Maps class at all

Comment: my position is int and I receive final int position, and converted int to string but still same error. Have updated my code above.

Comment: Are you sure your `position` variable is an int? What does `print(position); ` actually print?

Comment: On the first page on click on a list, position prints an array of value e.g "id": "1", "name": "John" etc but it is not navigating to the Map page.

Comment: Well, then obviously it's **not** an `int` then, is it?

Comment: it is all in the above code. Please help look to solve it. dealData
         .map(
   
           (position)

Comment: So what **is** `dealData`?

Comment: List dealData = List();